# ROC curve is missing 3 of 5 points

Tags: r, roc

I am trying to construct a ROC curve with points but only 2 of 5 points are showing up and I'm not sure why? What am I missing? Did I calculate the volume.value of the 3 variables incorrectly?(`roc_max_inf_vol`, `roc_med_adult_vol`, and `roc_med_inf_vol` do not appear). I am plotting (`1 - prop.adults`) versus (`1 - prop.infants`). Each point should correspond to the `volume.value` of the following variables (`roc_max_diff` and `roc_a1_i` are only 2 points that show up correctly):

These 2 show up correctly:

```
roc_max_diff <- volume.value[which.max(smooth.difference)]
roc_a1_i <- volume.value[volume.value > max(mydata[mydata$CLASS == "A1" & mydata$TYPE == "I", "VOLUME"])]
```

These 3 ***do not*** appear:

```
roc_max_inf_vol <- volume.value[max(mydata$VOLUME[mydata$TYPE == "I"])] 
roc_med_adult_vol <- volume.value[median(mydata$VOLUME[mydata$TYPE=="ADULT"])]
roc_med_inf_vol <- volume.value[median(mydata$VOLUME[mydata$TYPE=="I"])]
```

Here is what I have:

```
cuts <- which(volume.value %in% c(roc_max_inf_vol, roc_med_adult_vol, max_diff, a1_i, roc_med_inf_vol))

ggplot(mapping = aes((1 - prop.infants), (1 - prop.adults))) + 
    geom_line(color = 'darkblue', size = 1) + 

geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = 'darkred', linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes((1 - prop.infants[cuts]), (1 - prop.adults[cuts])),
             shape = 21, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", label = paste('Median infant \nvol =', round(med_inf_vol, 1)),
           x = 0.58, y = 0.90, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", label = paste('Zero A1 infants \nvol =', round(a1_i, 1)), 
           x = 0.25, y = 0.90, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", label = paste('Max difference \nvol =', round(max_diff, 1)), 
           x = 0.25, y = 0.68, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", label = paste('Median adult \nvol =', round(med_adult_vol, 1)), 
           x = 0.12, y = 0.46, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", label = paste('Protect all infants \nvol =', round(max_inf_vol, 1)),
           x = 0.09, y = 0.20, size = 3) +
  labs(title = "ROC curve of adult and infant harvest proportions",
       x = "Infant harvest proportion", y = "Adult harvest proportion") + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5))
```

For reference, here is the raw data I'm using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandahappy204/Sample/main/mydata.csv

And here are some background variables I think are needed to make sense of the above (like the prop.infants and prop.adults). Any help is much appreciated.

```
mydata$TYPE <- factor(ifelse(mydata$SEX == "I", "I", "ADULT"))
mydata$TYPE[mydata$CLASS == "A4" | mydata$CLASS == "A5"] <- "ADULT"

idxi <- mydata$TYPE == "I"
idxa <- mydata$TYPE == "ADULT"

max.v <- max(mydata$VOLUME)
min.v <- min(mydata$VOLUME)
delta <- (max.v - min.v)/10000
prop.infants <- numeric(10000)
prop.adults <- numeric(10000)
volume.value <- numeric(10000)

total.infants <- sum(idxi)  
total.adults <- sum(idxa)

for (k in 1:10000) { 
    value <- min.v + k*delta
    volume.value[k] <- value
    prop.infants[k] <- sum(mydata$VOLUME[idxi] <= value)/total.infants
    prop.adults[k] <-  sum(mydata$VOLUME[idxa] <= value)/total.adults
}

y.loess.a <- loess(1 - prop.adults ~ volume.value, span = 0.25,
    family = c("symmetric"))
y.loess.i <- loess(1 - prop.infants ~ volume.value, span = 0.25,
    family = c("symmetric"))
smooth.difference <- predict(y.loess.a) - predict(y.loess.i)
```

Comment: Joe, I would like to help, but the sheer amount of things I have to redo to construct your (main) problem is overwhelming. If you want to plot 5 points, why not extracting that final dataframe that you use to construct your ggplot? This allows to immediately spot your problem (or even you yourself). It will also answer whether you calculated something correctly. Generally, `ggplot()` works with dataframes. Your prop.infants/adults should be columns in a data frame that you supply (notwithstanding that you can provide vectors to a ggplot in certain layer calls). Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Welcome to this site Joe! It's really hard to run your code as it's not appearing in order... and needs to be run from the bottom up. But the real problem is that even then it doesn't run. For instance I still get an error: `Error in which.max(smooth.difference) : 
  object 'smooth.difference' not found`. Make sure the code you include is reproducible ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that, Calimo! I added the smooth.difference object so hopefully it will run, if you're able to try again. Thanks for your help.